# iOS download data from the web issues, NSURL

Tags: iphone, ios, download, nsurl

Need your quick advise.   I am create a "Currency Converter" iPhone app to retrieve the data from google currency websites.  It is work perfectly to download the string of USD -> AUD, USD->CAD, USD->HKD, USD->HUF, USD->JPY.  However, I don't why is **NOT** working and return **NULL** when try to retrieve USD->KRW and USD->ZMK.  Please refer the code as below.

```
 -(void)loadData:(NSString*)countryName{
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSString *responseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?%@", countryName];
        NSLog(@"URL:%@", responseURL);

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:responseURL]];

        theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

 }

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
         [connection release];

         NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"This is the responseString %@", responseString);
             [responseString release];


 }
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         [self loadData:@"AUD"];
         [self loadData:@"CAD"];
         [self loadData:@"HKD"];
         [self loadData:@"HUF"];
         [self loadData:@"JPY"];
         [self loadData:@"KRW"];
         [self loadData:@"ZMK"];
  }
```

Result from Console:

```
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.877 Converter[1691:f503] URL:http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?AUD
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.879 Converter[1691:f503] URL:http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?CAD
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.879 Converter[1691:f503] URL:http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?HKD
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.879 Converter[1691:f503] URL:http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?HUF
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.879 Converter[1691:f503] URL:http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?JPY
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.879 Converter[1691:f503] URL:http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?KRW
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.879 Converter[1691:f503] URL:http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=1USD=?ZMK
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.952 Converter[1691:f503] This is the responseString {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "1.02228583 Australian dollars",error: "",icc: true}
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.962 Converter[1691:f503] This is the responseString {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "7.79149947 Hong Kong dollars",error: "",icc: true}
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.966 Converter[1691:f503] This is the responseString {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "215.889465 Hungarian forints",error: "",icc: true}
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.982 Converter[1691:f503] This is the responseString {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "1.03910031 Canadian dollars",error: "",icc: true}
 2011-09-30 18:03:50.993 Converter[1691:f503] This is the responseString {lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "76.5579544 Japanese yen",error: "",icc: true}
 2011-09-30 18:03:51.010 Converter[1691:f503] This is the responseString (null)
 2011-09-30 18:03:51.047 Converter[1691:f503] This is the responseString (null)
```

Please help and much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it look like is ok to me either... However, don't know why is not working.... so weird... Do you think it is because of the string size it return?? Because the difference between USD->KRW USD->ZMK to to others is the return value is 4 positive digits.  Others is lesser than 3 positive digits... ...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't share `responseData` with all the requests, since they're sent asynchronously they will all finish at a random time, and you're probably writing all received data (from all requests) in `responseData`. Each request should have its own resources (`resourceData`, `theConnection`).

Have a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for a simple solution.